# Fetching IP when client in WiFi zone without sending any request

Tags: ip, wifi, ip-address, server

I want to know the IP address of the client (android phone) when it connects to my college WiFi, in the server application which is running on my college server.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Can you give us some background. Why do you need the IP and what would you do with it, how does your infrastructure looks like (AP hardware), etc.

Comment: @pajaja its on local network.....and i want to push data to the client when it is connected to the wifi.

Comment: By 'client' you mean android phone or some application on that phone? If you have the application installed make it check for the server and report it's IP after connecting to college WiFi. If you mean android phone we still don't know how would you push data to the phone and what kind of data it is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

You need to create PHP / JSP file on your server which contain code to connect to wifi Modem then scrap connected ip.

before you can do that you need the following requirements.

- already know the ip of modem
- already know the username and the password
- already know the page which contain connected IP

you can use CURL function in PHP.

Comment: yes, we can do that manually opening that page, but how would our server application know that? Does WiFi router provides any Service for that?

Comment: what do you meant by server application ? example please.

Comment: means like servlet/jsp/php running on server